# What does 'require()' return?

Tags: require

When you call `require()` with an argument that equals false, require will throw an error, the rest of the code will not be executed and the transaction will revert.

If you call it with an argument that equals true, the code will just run as expected.

So what does require return? Say if you went `if(require(false)) {}`, what would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `require` function does not return anything. You can't use it as `if(require(false)) {}`, it will not compile.

If the condition passed to the `require` function is true, nothing happens, and the code keeps executing. If the condition returns false, then `require` throws an `Error` with no data, or optionally an `Error(string)`, with the string message that you pass as the second argument to the `require` function:

```js
require(false, "There was an error");
```

Check the docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/control-structures.html#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require

Answer (score 0):

An `Error(string)` exception (or an exception without data) is generated by the compiler if calling `require(x)` where x evaluates to `false`.

See: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/control-structures.html